# How to architect serverless transformation of files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, error-handling, aws-lambda, status

I am designing a system where I want to use the serverless functions of AWS and S3 buckets.

I have some Word files in an S3 bucket and want to do some transformation on the files (this code will be written by me, which I want to host using using serverless functions, let's say the name of this service is `FileTransformation` service) and generate new files.

Suppose the user sends a request to transform the files, and the request includes the name of the files.

Now I have the following questions:

- I don't want the services to do **sequential** stuff, for example if `user1` has given the 10 file names in the request and another `user2` has also given a request for another 15 files. I don't want something like "once `user1` request is finished then `user2` requests should start". How should I can handle this?
- Suppose `user1` and `user2` asked for the status of their request, how can I report this? Does this need something extra to be done into my    `FileTransformation` service?
- How can I notify the user if a request fails?

Is there any AWS service I should consider while developing the above service?

I think we can use message broker to send requests to service. CloudWatch for error reporting or something.

Comment: SQS, SNS or SES.

Comment: Will all of the uploaded files require transformation? I ask this because the more "serverless" method would be to immediately trigger the transformation as soon as the files are uploaded. That way, the user never needs to request the transformation — they can simply download the results, or go to a "status page" that shows them the transformed files that they can download.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein no, design is like we will have bucket name, name of the files as parameter to the request and also the output files files will be in the same bucket.

Answer (score 2):

Your design could look like this:

1. S3 Bucket has an objectCreated event trigger (setup on S3 bucket notifications section) that will trigger a Lambda for processing
2. Files get uploaded to S3 Bucket
3. Each file triggers a Lambda to process it (concurrent Lambdas so this is **not** sequential
4. If the Lambda encounters an error, it can notify the user (see note below addressing this concern)
5. Once the Lambda completes processing, it can do whatever you wish it to do (such as emailing the result through SES, or storing the resulting file in S3)

> I don't want the services to do sequential stuff

When you use AWS Lambda, which is serverless, your Lambda will run multiple concurrent instances (which you can cap and/or reserve using the reserved concurrent executions value).

> Suppose the user1 and user2 asked for status of their request

To support this, you might want to implement a DynamoDB that holds the status of each request. When a Lambda gets triggered it can write to DynamoDB with a status saying "in progress", which it can then update to "completed" or "failed" accordingly. Then, you will have a separate API that reads that table whenever a user requests an update

> How can i notify user if request fails in between?

You can upload the file with a prefix that contains the user's email, or any other notification medium, for example: `files/userA/userA@test.com/file.doc`. This way, when the Lambda gets triggered and starts processing, if it fails processing it knows what email to send the result to.

**Edit:**
Based off the comment, if you want an approach where the file is already present in S3 and a user requests processing, then simply send the user's messages to an SQS queue, and then have a Lambda trigger for it (it will trigger concurrent executions of Lambdas to process the queue, not sequential). Or, you could have the API directly call the Lambda, and then have the user wait (if the processing is relatively quick, this should be fine as well)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but as you specified in point 1 each file can trigger as long as it is created but my case is files are already there in S3, what i want is when user sends a request like transform fileswith name then my Lamda should trigger, 
Is it fine to use some msg broker in between(can you specify which one to use) and then my fileservice will get msg and will concurrent lamdas trigger from there?

Comment: Edited my answer to include this scenario

Comment: Processing will take some time, Why did you suggested to use DynamoDB not mangoDB any specific reason?
Another thing can i specify user how much Percentage(%) is completed, i mean if user asked to transform 10 files and 6 have been processed and 7 is in process how can i tell user 60% is done, is it updating DB again and again after each file transform.

Another case: If transformation of 8th file is failed out of 10, how can i tell user 8th file failed and can my lamda service has retry logic, i mean do i need to put in my code or aws can help?

Comment: DynamoDB is serverless, I'm not sure if there is a fully serverless Mongo DB in AWS...DynamoDB I find a lot easier to use especially for simple cases like this. But yes, you would update the table with each status (keep in mind if you write your Lambda in python or nodejs it's very easy to make them async, and so the update calls don't hurt your overall process time). If you wanted to note that 8th file failed, you'd have to mention that in the code and then update the table for that accordingly

Comment: Python async example/link would be a good help too.
Let me think more and come out few more questions for you.
But your answers are really helping me out, you are awesome man.
Do you have any github profile where i can stay connected with you.
Do you think any more efficient performance things that can help to design above system,

Comment: I believe the question has been answered? If you have more questions, more specific questions that is, open new posts. This isn't how Stack Overflow is intended to be used. It's not a site where someone plans your app for you. Please read the rules.

Comment: Glad I can be of help :) you can message me on reddit (u/deivv on reddit) if you'd like more assistance, since otherwise this question can get off topic (in the mean time you can select an answer and mark the question as solved). However, for Python there are some [good documentations by AWS concerning async I/O](https://aioboto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html).